# Creating Alert Dialog box in Android and add a button to Dialog (popup) to close it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog, android-button

I am creating a About us screen as a popup/dialog in android. I want to add a button (OK or CANCEL) to this dialog. How can I do that ?

This is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/popup"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#E3C39D"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About Us.."
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        style="@style/TextShadow"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height= "1dp"
        android:background="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Hello ! I want to put a button below with label 'OK' and Click on this OK button the popup should be close. Thank you !" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and below is the function for Dialog box

```
public void AboutUsDialog(){
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert;
        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_about_us, null);
        alert.setView(dialogView);
        alert.show();

        alert.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
        //alert.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    }
```

I am using `alert.setPositiveButton("OK",null);` or `alert.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);`. But I did not get any button displayed in dialog.

Now Dialog gets OFF when I touch anywhere on the screen. I want to close popup through OK button only.

Thanks in advance!

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my code to add buttons.

```
public void AboutUsDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert;
        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_about_us, null);
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);  //This is my Solution to this question(adding OK button)
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
        alert.setView(dialogView);
        alert.show();
        //alert.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your button is not coming because it should be like this

```
alert.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
alert.setView(dialogView);
        alert.show();
```

Instead of

```
alert.setView(dialogView);
        alert.show();
alert.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
```

Refer this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure,You wanted to make decision");

      alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You clicked yes button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
      });

      alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
         }
      });

      AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
      alertDialog.show();
```

Try and let me know

Comment: Did u try the above one

Comment: @AbhishekTandon set `dialog.setCancelable(false)` to disable dialog dismissing on clicking of screen.